# .gitlab-ci.yml cache/artifact configuration for saving large binaries for subsequent pipeline/stages based on condition

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops

## background

I am setting up a ci/cd for a python project that has a c++ library dependence that is in the folder `foo/bar/c_code_src`. The build stage runs `python setup.py install` and compiles the c++ library binaries and output it to `foo/bar/bin/`

I then run a python unittest that fails if `foo/bar/bin` doesn't exists.

The script below is my first attempt at using `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - python setup.py install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - foo/bar/c_code_src

test:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - build
  script:
 - python -m unittest foo/bar/test_bar.py
```

This is able to work fine however because it takes a relatively long time to compile `c_code_src`, and the resulting bin is fairly large, and the code in `c_code_src` doesn't change much I want to be able to cache the `bin` folder for future pipelines and only run build stage if the code in `c_code_src` changes. after reading the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cache) it seems that I want to use `cache` instead of (or along side with) `artifacts`.

Here is my attempt at revising the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - python setup.py install
  cache:
  - key: bar_cache
    paths:
    - foo/bar/bin
  
test_bar:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - build
  cache:
    key: bar_cache
    paths:
    - foo/bar/bin
    policy: pull
  script:
 - python -m unittest foo/bar/test_bar.py
```

What I am unsure of is how to set the condition that only run build if `c_code_src` changes.

In short I want:

- only run build if `bin` does not exists or there's changes to `c_code_src`
- cache `bin` such that the test stage always have the up-to-date `bin` even if build stage did not run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you'd be able to have a condition where `bin` does not exist, because typically, the job condition will look at what changes are being made in a commit without running through the whole repository code.

You can however fairly easily make the job check for changes. You can either use [only:changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges) or [rules:changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges). So for the relevant job, add:

```
  rules:
    changes:
    - foo/bar/c_code_src/*
```

As to caching, what you've written looks fine. [Cache isn't always guaranteed to work](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/index.html) but will pull a new version if necessary, so having the most recent shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: hmm my problem is that if cache doesn't work but build does not run since c_code_src does not change then bin will never be made

Comment: The unittest failed, yes. Is there ever a time where cache exists for build stage but does not exist for test stage if I use a single runner?

Comment: if it's on a single runner and everything has been set up correctly, then generally, it should work. As your original question was more focused on the yml, you might want to pose the error/issue as a separate question. You may also want to consider cross-posting to the GitLab forum

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will try that.